# Combination with exclusion of some pairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ elements and $Q$ be a subset of $P$ having $m < n$ elements.

How many subsets of $P$ containing $k$ elements are there, such that no two elements of $Q$ appear together?

For example, if
$P = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, and
$Q = \{1,2,4,7\}$,
then {2,3,5,6} is a valid subset of size $4$, but these are invalid ones:

- {1,2,5,6}, because 1 and 2 cannot appear together;
- {1,2,6,7}, because both 1 and 2, and 1 and 7 cannot appear together.
- {1,2,4,7}, because 1,2; 1,4; 1,7; 2,4; 2,7 and 4,7 cannot appear together.

---

My thoughts:

I can make $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of $P$. Then I have to subtract all invalid ones. I can pick one "bad" pair from $Q$ and count how many subsets of size $k$ contains that pair: $\binom{m}{2}\binom{n-2}{k-2}$.
I'd end up with: $\binom{n}{k} - \binom{m}{2}\binom{n-2}{k-2}$.

But this is excluding too much! For instance, both $\{1,2,4,7\}$ and $\{1,2,4,5\}$ are being counted multiple times. Now I should add back all the subsets with two pairs, and then subtract again all subsets with three pairs and so on.

But this is where I am stuck: how can I count the combinations having $p>1$ "bad" pairs?

---

This is a generalization of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434967/combinations-with-exclusions) question.

Comment: Going on with the example: why not counting all subsets of $P-Q$ that have $4$ elements and adding $4$ times all subsets of $P-Q$ that have $3$ elements (each of them is made a set of $4$ by adding an element of $Q$ and there are $4$ such elements)?

Comment: @drhab, you're right. I just tested it and it works. Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for a very long time, and I was just having the wrong point of view. Thank you again. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad to help. I do not mind it all if you accept the anwer that showed up in the meanwhile. An answer of me would be practically the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier to consider that there are two mutually exclusive cases, depending on whether $(0)$ or $(1)$ element is taken from $Q$.

So, the enumeration is

$$\binom{n-m}{k} + \left[\binom{n-m}{k-1} \times \binom{m}{1}\right].$$